# Syncfusion Winforms SpreadsheetRibbon throws exception when added through Designer or on compile

Tags: c#, winforms, syncfusion

Okay, this is a weird one. I developed a small WinForms .NET7 application which uses both Syncfusion's Spreadsheet and the SpreadsheetRibbon control to display some Excel data (and then do stuff to said data).
This application is previewed in the Designer just fine and also compiles and runs on my Desktop PC (Windows 11 Pro with VS2022 Enterprise, i9-11900)

Then I wanted to do some more development on that application and cloned the application's source from my Github repo to my Surface Book 3 (also Win11 Pro with VS2022 Enterprise).

I then waited for the Nuget packages to be instantiated and hit "Debug". Which then crashed out with the following exception:

[image]

Keep in mind that I simply dragged the controls from the Toolbox and did nothing more than to tell the SpreadsheetRibbon the reference to the Spreadsheet control. Everything else is on default properties.

It's then that I noticed that the Ribbon does not show up in the Designer preview. Trying to drag another Ribbon onto the Designer from the Toolbox yields a similar exception:

[image]

Which is very weird and I don't see where that is coming from. After all, it works on my Desktop PC and both my laptop and my desktop have the same configuration for VS2022.
Plus, I recently reset my laptop so currently there's actually nothing installed that should interfere with the build process.
I already asked on Syncfusion's forums but I didn't get the impression that they understood the problem... anyone else have an idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Because my application also worked and compiled on a Surface Go 2 with an otherwise identical software configuration. So it must be hardware related.
Well, the stack trace when trying to run the app mentioned an issue with a bitmap and `System.Drawing` - so maybe graphics related?

And that's when I remembered the VS banner on my Surface Book which mentioned that there was an issue with the scaling factor of 200%.

Long story short: Setting the scaling factor to 100% makes everything work.